# How to Link Liquibase to SQL Server 2008

Tags: liquibase

Can anyone help me in linking SQL sever 2008 to liquibase ? 
It would provide me with correct steps inorder to do it

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "linking"? You don't "link" Liquibase, you create a changeLog script and "run" that through Liquibase. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the error you get? Show us the commands you used to run Liqubiase (and e.g. the contents of your `liquibase.properties` file)

Comment: How to run the liquibase through command line? I need the basic installation steps of liquibase to start of with. Since I am new to liquibase. I am using SQL server database and also installed JDBC driver. How exactly will liquibase fetch the changes through liquibase ??

Comment: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

Comment: --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
--classpath=D:\JDBC\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc41.jar
--url=jdbc:sqlserver://nyxstktestsql01.nyxinteractive.com.local:1433;databaseName=Test;integratedSecurity=true;   --changeLogFile=changelog.xml    ... I am trying to execute using command line but giving error not recognized as internal or external command. Please let me know what's the mistake I am doing.
Thanks,